# Expanding individual Cards with React + Material UI Card Expander

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, expand

I'm using React + Material UI to create 3 expandable cards with images. Everything is working fine, I can render the cards and they are expanding (almost) the way I wanted to. The problem is: *ALL cards are expanding at the same time* and **I want just ONE to expand** when the user click on it.

I know I should somehow use states to deal with this issue, but I'm not sure HOW to do it. Any insights? Please, feel free to share code or to point me in the right direction.

CodeSandBox in case anyone want to give it a shot (please fork before coding!):
https://codesandbox.io/s/mutable-dust-lwljo

This is my card component:

```
/* eslint-disable linebreak-style */
/* eslint-disable react/prop-types */
/* eslint-disable semi */
/* eslint-disable linebreak-style */
import React from 'react'
import CardHeader from '@material-ui/core/CardHeader'
import CardContent from '@material-ui/core/CardContent'
import CardActions from '@material-ui/core/CardActions'
import Collapse from '@material-ui/core/Collapse'
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton'
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography'
import FavoriteIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Favorite'
import ExpandMoreIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore'
import { CardLayout, CardImg } from './SiteCardStyled'


export class SiteCard extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state ={
            expanded: false,
        }
    }

    handleExpandClick = () => {
        this.setState({expanded: !this.state.expanded})
    };

    render() {

        let expanded = this.state.expanded

        return <CardLayout>
            <CardHeader
                title={this.props.cardtitle}
                subheader={this.props.cardsubheader}
            />
            <CardImg
                image={this.props.media}
                title={this.props.mediatitle}
            />
            <CardContent>
                <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" component="p">
                    {this.props.carddescription}
                </Typography>
            </CardContent>
            <CardActions disableSpacing>
                <IconButton aria-label="add to favorites">
                    <FavoriteIcon />
                </IconButton>
                <IconButton
                    onClick={this.handleExpandClick}
                    //AQUI
                    aria-expanded={expanded}
                    aria-label="Ver mais"
                >
                    <ExpandMoreIcon />
                </IconButton>
            </CardActions>
            {/* aqui */}
            <Collapse in={expanded} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
                <CardContent>
                    <Typography paragraph>{this.props.cardexpandedtitle}</Typography>
                    <Typography paragraph>
                        {this.props.cardexpandedtext}
                    </Typography>
                </CardContent>
            </Collapse>
        </CardLayout>
    }
}
```

And here is where I call the component + props:

```
/* eslint-disable linebreak-style */
import React from 'react'
import { MainPage, MainPageWrapper, SiteCardArea } from './AppContainerStyled'
import { MenuTop } from './MenuTop/MenuTop'
import { MainText } from './MainText/MainText'
import { SiteCard } from './SiteCard/SiteCard'

export class AppContainer extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }


    render() {

        return <MainPage>

            <MainPageWrapper>

                <MenuTop></MenuTop>
                <MainText></MainText>
                <SiteCardArea>
                    <SiteCard
                        cardtitle={'title'}
                        cardsubheader={'subheader'}
                        mediatitle={'mediatitle'}
                        media={'https://i.picsum.photos/id/682/300/300.jpg'}
                        carddescription={'sitedescription'}
                        cardexpandedtitle={'cardexpandedtitle'}
                        cardexpandedtext={'cardexpandedtext'}
                    ></SiteCard>
                    <SiteCard
                        cardtitle={'title2'}
                        cardsubheader={'subheader2'}
                        mediatitle={'mediatitle2'}
                        media={'https://i.picsum.photos/id/680/300/300.jpg'}
                        carddescription={'sitedescription2'}
                        cardexpandedtitle={'cardexpandedtitle2'}
                        cardexpandedtext={'cardexpandedtext2'}
                    ></SiteCard>
                    <SiteCard
                        cardtitle={'title3'}
                        cardsubheader={'subheader3'}
                        mediatitle={'mediatitle3'}
                        media={'https://i.picsum.photos/id/672/300/300.jpg'}
                        carddescription={'sitedescription3'}
                        cardexpandedtitle={'cardexpandedtitle3'}
                        cardexpandedtext={'cardexpandedtext3'}
                    ></SiteCard>
                </SiteCardArea>

            </MainPageWrapper>

        </MainPage>

    }
}
```

Maybe each card should have one state? But if that's the case, should I create a different function to deal with each card? I know I may be getting closer to the answer, but I'm stuck. Can anyone help? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Save title of the card in state, as it seems unique in your case, and open the specific card base on that title. Maybe name it as `activeTitle`.

Comment: Solved! The problem wasn't in the state after all. It was in the size of each card's parent container - as the card's size increased when expanded, each card would also increase its size looking like it was "expanded" too. I just had to add `height: 100%` to the card component and it's done. Thanks anyway!